# Importance of the factor $2^{-j}$ in measure theory

Tags: measure-theory

Could you explain, why the factor $2^{-j}$ is so important and useful in the proofs of theorems in measure theory? For example, for extending intervals from $I_j = (a_j,b_j)$ to $I'_j = (a_j-2^{-j}\epsilon/2, b_j+2^{-j}\epsilon/2)$.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Well, it is not really that for some reason it is more important than $3^{-j}$ for example, but the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}=1$ makes it pretty handy. In your example, let's say, taking the sums of all the intervals $I'_j$ you will get something like $\sum |I'_j|=\sum|I_j|+\epsilon$.

Comment: @Dim A Thank you for the explanation! Would you mind posting a reply to the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There no real *mathematical* reason that makes $2^{-j}$ more important than $3^{-j}$ or any arbitrary factor that can sum up, but the fact that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty 2^{-k}=1$ makes it pretty handy.

In your example, let's say, taking the sums of all the intervals I′j you will get something like $\sum_{j} |I'_j|=\sum_{j} |I'_j|+\epsilon$ (assuming that we can some up things in the first place). Using the factor $3^{-j}$ for example, would require setting $I'_j = (a_j-3^{-j}\epsilon/4, b_j+3^{-j}\epsilon/4)$ so that we get exactly $\epsilon$ on the RHS above, or $I'_j = (a_j-j^{-2}3\epsilon/\pi^2, b_j+j^{-2}3\epsilon/\pi^2)$ for a $j^{-2}$ factor, that may make things unclear.